# Where did Metternich say Asia/the Balkans begin at the Landstrasse/Rennweg? Does anyone have a source?

Tags: europe

I have found several variations on this, but always the source has been unattributed (or attributed to a source that itself has no attribution!)#
So - can anyone provide a contemporary source, and what was the actual comment?

der Balkan auf der Landstraße beginnt
der Balkan beginnt  am Rennweg
Asien beginnt auf dem landstrasse
Asien beginnt an dem landstrasse
Asien beginnt auf am Rennweg
Asien beginnt an dem landstrasse

Comment: This does not duplicate the other question about Metternich. That asks about where he said Asia began - which is one of the roads from Vienna. MY question is what is the SOURCE of this statement. Not to be pedantic, but would have hoped users of a website devoted to history might have spotted the difference.